# Multi-class time series data in LSTM

Tags: time-series, lstm

I have a data set that includes the individual performance of a number of "actors" over some period of time.

For a less-than-ideal contrived example (I'm not able to share the actual use case), you can imagine this is a set of stocks on the NYSE.  My goal is to use an LSTM model to predict T+1 value for a given actor

I have a dataframe which looks something like this:

```
+----------+---------+-----------+-----+-----------|-------+
|   Date   | ActorID | Feature 1 | ... | Feature X | Value |
+----------+---------+-----------+-----+-----------+-------+
| 1/1/2019 |       1 | 1.1       | ... | 0.123     | 1.111 |
| 1/2/2019 |       1 | 1.2       | ... | 0.456     | 1.222 |
| 1/3/2019 |       1 | 1.3       | ... | 0.789     | 1.333 |
| 1/1/2019 |       2 | 1.4       | ... | 0.123     | 1.444 |
| 1/2/2019 |       2 | 1.5       | ... | 0.456     | 1.555 |
| 1/3/2019 |       2 | 1.6       | ... | 0.789     | 1.666 |
+----------+---------+-----------+-----+-----------+-------+
```

My question is how to ideally feed this data into my LSTM model for training.  Do I flatten the dataframe and turn all the actors' data on a given day into a single array?  Do I feed them sequentially?

Any general direction on the approach here would be hugely helpful.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: When predicting the value at T+1, does your model know the features at T+1? In general *flatten* all the data in a single day is a good starting point to try.

Comment: @user12075 Interesting question... yes, the model will know most (but not all) features at T+1.  If I do flatten, how do I deal with a changing list of "actors"?

Comment: @R M With a "changing list of actors" it's hard to answer the question without knowing your detailed problem setup. For instance, when a "actor" is gone, does it still impose a similar influence on the 'value' as before? Does the list remain constant size? Those factors could influence how to best formulate the data.

Comment: @user12075 - Thanks for the replies.  Unfortunately I can't share the specific problem, but I can answer your question.  The list of "actors" changes throughout the duration of the dataset with each lasting some number of periods.  Once an actor is gone, it no longer influences the system (outside a minimal influence due to its absence). The "active" number of actors remains similar, but the total historical list continues to grow.  I suppose I can reserve space for all actors who have ever participated in the system, but this will make the problem far more computationally intensive...